# How to mark 'duplicated sequence' in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I want to mark the duplicate sequence in a list.

For example:

```
(1,1,1,0,2,3,2,4,2)
```

My expected result is:

```
(True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False)
```

I tried `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated(keep=False)`, but it marks '2' as duplicated:

```
(True,True,True,False,True,False,True,False,True).
```

How to mark the 'duplicated sequence' only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for helper `Series` where apply [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,4,2,2,1])
print (s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False).values)
[False False  True  True False  True  True False False  True  True False]
```

Detail:

```
print (s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     5
7     6
8     7
9     8
10    8
11    9
dtype: int32
```

Comment: I tried this solution, it works! 
cumsum() is interesting way. your solution opens my mind. Pandas is a real powerful tool. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shift` i.e

```
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,0,2,3,2,4,2])
mask = (s == s.shift().bfill())
```

or Thanks @Zero

```
mask = s.diff().bfill().eq(0)

print tuple(mask)

(True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False)
```

In case you have sequence at the end comparing two masks would be helpful i.e

```
n = pd.Series([1,1,1,0,2,3,2,4,2,2])
mask = (n==n.shift(-1).ffill()) | (n==n.shift().bfill())

tuple(mask) 
(True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, True)
```

Comment: Or, `s.diff().bfill().eq(0)`

Comment: Thanks, it works.

s == s.shift().bfill() is a good idea. as a fresh hand in pandas, it inspires me how to think in matrix calculating. thanks again.

Comment: Go for @ jez solution it suits all cases